# C++ Postfix Calculator not working with 2 operands in a row

Tags: c++, vector, calculator, postfix-mta

Hello I have written a postfix calculator using vectors (which is required) and have run into trouble. When I enter two operands in a row, it won't give the correct answer. For example, "5 4 + 3 10 * +" gives the answer "36" when it should give 39. I understand why it isn't working I just can't think of a way to do it where it handles that case. Can someone give me a hand?
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//splits the string into different parts seperated by space and stores in tokens
void SplitString(string s, char delim, vector<string> &tokens)
{
stringstream ss;
ss.str(s);
string item;
while(getline(ss, item, delim))
{
    tokens.push_back(item);
}
}

//preforms the operation denoted by the operand 
void operation(string operand, vector<int> &eqVec)
{
int temp1 = eqVec.at(0);
int temp2 = eqVec.at(1);

if(operand == "+")
{
    eqVec.push_back(temp1 + temp2);

}
else if(operand == "-")
{
    eqVec.push_back(temp1 - temp2);
}
else if(operand == "*")
{
    eqVec.push_back(temp1 * temp2);
}
else if(operand == "/")
{
    eqVec.push_back(temp1 / temp2);
}

}

int main()
{
const char DELIM = ' ';
int total;
string eq;

vector <int> eqVec;
vector<string> tokens;


cout<<"Welcome to the postfix calculator! " << endl;
cout<<"Please enter your equation: ";

//gets the input and splits into tokens
getline(cin, eq);
SplitString(eq, DELIM, tokens); 

//cycles through tokens
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i)
{

    //calls operation when an operand is encountered
    if(tokens.at(i) == "+" || tokens.at(i) == "-" || tokens.at(i) == "*" || tokens.at(i) == "/")
    {
        operation(tokens.at(i), eqVec);
    }

    //otherwise, stores the number into next slot of eqVec
    else
    {

        //turns tokens into an int to put in eqVec
        int temp = stoi(tokens.at(i));
        eqVec.push_back(temp);
    }

}

//prints out only remaining variable in eqVec, the total
cout<<"The answer is: " << eqVec.at(0) << endl;






return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I just can't think of a way to do it where it handles that case* -- You should have first created a plan to handle these cases before writing any code.  What can wind up happening is that you've coded yourself "into a corner" that would require a total rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break and coming back I found a way to solve it. Posting here in case anyone in the future has the same problem. The following block of code is now at the beginning of the operation function before the series of if statements.

```
int temp1, temp2;
int size = eqVec.size();
if(size > 2)
{
    temp1 = eqVec.at(size - 1);
    temp2 = eqVec.at(size - 2);
    eqVec.pop_back();
    eqVec.pop_back();
}
else
{
    temp1 = eqVec.at(0);
    temp2 = eqVec.at(1);
    eqVec.pop_back();
    eqVec.pop_back();
}
```